# One GET request not working in Safari ( Authorization issue) - Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular

I found this issue in multiple places, but no clear solution. Just one get request is not working (401 Unauthorized), but when I look at debugger the code works fine, and all other requests are working fine. Chrome and Firefox work fine as well, no issues.

This is my interceptor service:

```
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(public auth: LoginService) {}
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        // Get the auth header from the service.
        let authHeader = this.auth.getToken();
        if (!authHeader) {
            authHeader = '';
        }
        let authReq: any;
        // Clone the request to add the new header.
        if (this.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
            authHeader = authHeader.replace(/^"(.*)"$/, '$1'); // Remove quotes from token start/end.
            authReq = request.clone({headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + authHeader)});
        } else {
            authReq = request.clone({headers: request.headers.set('Token', authHeader)});
        }

        // Pass on the cloned request instead of the original request.
        return next.handle(authReq);
    }
}
```

Anyone has an advice?

Comment: "One request is not working, but the code works fine". Well decide :) "Not working" how? What's the error stack?

Comment: @LazarLjubenović "when I look at debugger, the code works fine", it goes through the code, but I do not have Authorization in request headers at all. Its 401 error, unauthorized

Comment: Did you try adding a trailing slash to the requested resource? Can we see the code which fires a request which doesn't get the header added?

Comment: That was the issue.. @LazarLjubenović thanks, never would have checked that

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add `/` and the end of the api end point. For example this will not work:

```
http://www.example.com/api/skill
```

but this will work:

```
http://www.example.com/api/skill/
```

Comment: Both your examples were the same - I edited your answer to fix it (using example.com instead of test.com). Please roll back if my edit was incorrect.